# SQL - Normalizing a table containing multiple choices

Tags: mysql, database, database-normalization

I trying to create a database that includes a table, which will have the answers to a multiple choice quiz..
My problem is that, is it normal to create a column for every question?

I mean like if I have 100 questions do I create a column for every one of them?

What is the best approach for this?

Thank you

Comment: Questions should be _rows_ (records), not columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this link
Table: User

- user_id auto integer
- regtime datetime
- username varchar
- useremail varchar
- userpass varchar

Table: Questions

- question_id auto integer
- question varchar
- is_active enum(0,1)

Table: Question_choices

- choice_id auto integer
- question_id integer
- is_correct_choice enum(0,1)
- choice varchar

Table: User_question_answer

- user_id integer
- question_id integer
- choice_id integer
- is_correct enum(0,1)
- answer_time datetime

https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-good-database-schema-using-MySQL-for-storing-multiple-choice-questions

Answer (score 1):

It's *normal* (both in the ordinary sense and in the database-normalizing sense) to create a *row* for every question. And in another table create a *row* for every answer.

Read about database normalization.

Your `question` table might have columns with values like this

```
question_id   question_text
          1   What color is the sky?
          2   What number comes after 1?
```

and your `answer` table might have columns with values like this

```
answer_id   question_id  correct  answer_text
        1             1        0  Green
        2             1        1  Blue
        3             1        0  Orange
        4             2        0  -2
        5             2        1  2
        6             2        0  42
        7             2        0  π
```

With a design such as this you can add as many questions and answers as you require without changing the structure of your tables.

You can retrieve the correct answer, for example, to every question like this

```
   SELECT question_text, answer_text
     FROM question
     JOIN answer ON question.question_id = answer.question_id
    WHERE answer.correct = 1
```